iLogic from external program
Is it possible to call up and use the iLogic add-in via an external program?
I have created a .net 8.0 console project and tried to read the names of objects (areas). This would have allowed me to create an assignment between the two surfaces during runtime.
These would be my references in the project

Initialization of the Inventor application
 private static void StartInventorApplication()
 {
     try
     {
         //InventorApplication = (Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Inventor.Application");
         InventorApplication = (Application)getActiveObject("Inventor.Application");
     }
     catch (COMException)
     {
         Type ApplicationType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Inventor.Application");

         InventorApplication = (Application)Activator.CreateInstance(ApplicationType);
         InventorApplication.Visible = true;
     }

     Console.WriteLine("Inventor Application started");
 }

Loading of the CAD assembly
        private static void LoadCADAssembly()
        {            
            string CADAssemblyPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(ProjectFolder, "Bauteil4.ipt");

            Documents ApplicationDocument = (Documents)InventorApplication.Documents;

            CurrentDocument = ApplicationDocument.Open(CADAssemblyPath, true);

            Console.WriteLine($"Model '{CADAssemblyPath}' loaded successfully.");

            CurrentDocument.Activate();
        }

Create the iLogic AddIn
 private static void CreateAutomation()
 {
  string iLogicAddinGuid = "{3BDD8D79-2179-4B11-8A5A-257B1C0263AC}";
  
  try
  {
      InventoriLogicAddIn = InventorApplication.ApplicationAddIns.get_ItemById(iLogicAddinGuid);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      throw ex;
  }

  if (InventoriLogicAddIn != null)
  {
      if (!InventoriLogicAddIn.Activated)
      {
          InventoriLogicAddIn.Activate();
      }
   }
 }

Use the iLogic Addin to find the names of the faces in the part
 private static void UseiLogicAutomation()
{
 dynamic ActiveDocument = InventorApplication.ActiveDocument;
 dynamic MyAutomation = InventoriLogicAddIn.Automation;
 
 if (MyAutomation != null)
 {                
     NamedEntities NameList = MyAutomation.GetNamedEntities(ActiveDocument);
     
     if (NameList != null)
     {
         //int count = NameList.Count;
         //for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
         //{
         //    dynamic entity = NameList.Item(i);
         //    Console.WriteLine(entity.Name);
         //}
       }
   }
 }

But I get following error

Why can't the object be cast correctly? If I simply use "dynamic" instead of the "NamedEntities" class, I can read it out but not access it because the properties such as "Name" do not exist.  Also, I cannot run through the list at all.

Does anyone here know more about this?
Thanks.

Check if you compile your application for x64. This is the most common reason for InvalidCastException. Also check if the used Inventor version is 2025 and above. Older Inventor versions uses .NET Framework 4.8.

The version is Inventor 2025 and I have compiled as x64

There are some issues with types conversion in external application. But you can try different approach. iLogic uses Attributes functionality in the background and you can bypass iLogic with standard API calls. Below is a sample which obtains all available names in active document and gets the strongly typed entities by iLogic name.
using Inventor;
using Attribute = Inventor.Attribute;

// SimpleExe.MarshalCore becomes from SDK 2025
// ...\DevTools_2025\DeveloperTools\Samples\VCSharp.NET\Standalone Applications\Inventor\SimpleExe\MarshalCore.cs
object activeObject = SimpleExe.MarshalCore.GetActiveObject("Inventor.Application");
var inventor = activeObject as Application;
var document = inventor.ActiveDocument;

// Get available names of entities in given document
Console.WriteLine($"Available names in {document.DisplayName}:");
foreach (string name in GetNames(document))
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}

Console.WriteLine();

// Find objects by name without iLogic
var edge1 = FindObjectByName(document, "Edge0")[1] as Edge;
var face1 = FindObjectByName(document, "Face0")[1] as Face;

Console.WriteLine("Edge length: " + edge1.StopVertex.Point.DistanceTo(edge1.StartVertex.Point));
Console.WriteLine("Face area: " + face1.Evaluator.Area);

ObjectCollection FindObjectByName(Document document, string name)
{
    var objectCollection = document.AttributeManager.FindObjects("iLogicEntityNameSet", "iLogicEntityName", name);
    return objectCollection;
}

string[] GetNames(Document document)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    var attributes = document.AttributeManager.FindAttributes("iLogicEntityNameSet", "iLogicEntityName");
    foreach (Attribute attribute in attributes)
    {
        string name = attribute.Value?.ToString() ?? "";
        result.Add(name);
    }

    return result.ToArray();
}

